# I am trying to make a custom user model in django, but its giving me a lot of errors

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, settings, web-development-server

I am developing a Django project, so I have the scheduling app, the real function on the app, and I created an "accounts" app to modify the base User Model, so I can make the user log in with his/her email. If you can help me with this problem, I would really appreciate since I am kind of stuck.
However, now that I modified the models.py(in the "accounts" app) and modified the settings.py on the main website folder, I am getting the following errors(the last including an installed apps settings error, which I don't understand.:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/PythonProjects/tutorTrip/manage.py", line 15, in 
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "C:\Users\Alienware\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 371, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()   File "C:\Users\Alienware\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 365, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "C:\Users\Alienware\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
>   line 288, in run_from_argv
>       self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "C:\Users\Alienware\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py",
>   line 61, in execute
>       super().execute(*args, **options)   File "C:\Users\Alienware\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
>   line 335, in execute
>       output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "C:\Users\Alienware\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py",
>   line 70, in handle
>       if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:   File "C:\Users\Alienware\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\conf__init__.py",
>   line 56, in **getattr**
>       self._setup(name)   File "C:\Users\Alienware\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\conf__init__.py",
>   line 43, in _setup
>       self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)   File "C:\Users\Alienware\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\conf__init__.py",
>   line 120, in **init**
>       raise ImproperlyConfigured("The %s setting must be a list or a tuple. " % setting) django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The
>   INSTALLED_APPS setting must be a list or a tuple.
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Follow my code:

(accounts/models.py):

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager 
)
   class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
       def create_user(self, email, password=None, active=True, 
is_staff=False, is_admin=False):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("User must have an email")
       if not password:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a password")

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
        )
        user.set_password(password)  # change user password
        user.staff = is_staff
        user.admin = is_admin
       # user.active = is_active
       user.save(using=self._db)
       return user

def create_staffuser(self, email, password):
    # """
    # Creates and saves a staff user with the given email and password.
    # """
    user = self.create_user(
        email,
        password=password,
    )
    user.staff = True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

def create_superuser(self, email, password):
    # """
    # Creates and saves a superuser with the given email and password.
    # """
    user = self.create_user(
        email,
        password=password,
    )
    user.staff = True
    user.admin = True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user


# user class
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
        verbose_name='email address',
    )
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)  # can login
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    objects = UserManager()

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

def get_full_name(self):
    return self.email

def get_short_name(self):
    return self.email

def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
    # "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
    # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
    return True

def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
    # "Does the user have a specific permission?"
    # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
    return True

@property
def is_staff(self):
    return self.staff

@property
def is_admin(self):
    return self.admin

@property
def is_active(self):
    return self.active


class Profile(models.Model):
#user = models.OneToOneField(User)
# extend extra user data
```

(website/settings.py)

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))




# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = {
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
    'scheduling.apps.SchedulingConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'tutorTrip.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
   },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'tutorTrip.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME':     'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME':     'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
},
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

If you need any additional piece of code, please let me know.
(Maybe dont consider the indentention, as I had some trouble copying into the code boxes here, some of them may show wrongly.)

Comment: It would be nice if you mark answers as correct so people know this was already answered.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Django DOC - **`INSTALLED_APPS`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#installed-apps),

> **A list of strings** designating all applications that are enabled in this Django installation. Which says

But, you are defined the **`INSTALLED_APPS`** as **set** object (**`{}`**). The **`{}`** syntax is used to represent the set objects

So change the **`INSTALLED_APPS`** to as below

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ..... # your apps
      ]
```

**Example**

```
In [1]: a = {1,3}

In [2]: b= [1,3]

In [3]: c = (1,3)

In [4]: type(a)
Out[4]: set

In [5]: type(b)
Out[5]: list

In [6]: type(c)
Out[6]: tuple
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is the ErrorMessage that you got which says

```
ImproperlyConfigured("The %s setting must be a list or a tuple. " % setting)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The INSTALLED_APPS setting must be a list or a tuple.
```

Change your installed apps datatype to a list by changing your `{}` to `[]`.